# how to make access auto rephrase a query response

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am using Microsoft Access and am designing a query that will decide whether the student is allowed or not however i need to be able to type "Approved" and for it to return all data entries that have yes answered to the question about lunch policy. I am currently using [Approved or Not?] and sadly my client requires this phrasing. Is it possible to type "approved" and it show all students with "Yes" to lunch policy. Many Thanks  Tom

Comment: Yes and No. No, if your data field has values of either "Yes" or "No", you can't filter that field on "Approved" (actually, you could, but you would get zero records!)  Yes, if you write your quert with an 'IIF' statement that translates 'Yes' to 'Approved' and 'No' to 'Not Approved', or you have a VBA interface that will translate 'Approved' to 'Yes' and use 'Yes' in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple query that **may** work - you don't mention the datatype of the field - is it Text, Boolean, or what?

```
SELECT Table1.FldA, IIf([FldA]='yes','Approved','Not Approved') AS Xlate
     FROM Table1
      WHERE (((IIf([FldA]='yes','Approved','Not Approved'))=[Is Student Approved?]));
```

Comment: It's text however i just tried it and it didn't seem to work? Do i need to change anything? I am not very experienced with wording queries

Comment: Substitute your Table Name and Field Name in place of 'Table1' and 'FldA'. Are you certain your table has 'Yes' (or 'yes') in your field? Please update your question with the SQL you are trying to run. What exactly did you enter for the prompt?